# What is my word? 2

Tags: word, word-property

***You have to try and guess what my word is from the clues.***

**My first part** is a negative relative
**My second part** is quite critical but also this
**The third part** is the foundations of something
**The fourth part** is what the reason is
**The fifth part** is all around  us, it is what we breathe
**The final part** is nearly realisation
***As per usal, I will post hints if needed***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is:

> antidisestablishmentarianism

First part:

> anti for negative, auntie for relationship (thanks @IT Alex)

Second part:

> dis as slang for this

Third:

> establish as a foundation

Fourth:

> ment as in meant?

Fifth:

> ari sounds like air, close enough?

Sixth:

> realisation or realization?
>  ism - a distinctive practice, system, or philosophy, typically a political ideology or an artistic movement.

Comment: rot 13: nhagvr nf nagv

Answer (score 3):

Are you?

> antidisestablishmentarianism

Drat beat to the punch. So I am going to solve some of Dorrulf's missing ones

Fourth

> Ment as in Meant as the reason

Fifth

> Ar pronounced as Air

Sixth

> Not sure

Comment: The sixth part is 'reanism' which is very close to realism pronunciation wise

Comment: My goodness that was close! +1